# Where to get Child of Atom rags?

Tags: fallout-4

I recently started a new character, where he aligns himself with Child of Atom. I've done the Far Harbour story, and I want to make some settlements for the cult. Just wondering if anyone has any places where Child of Atom clothing could be. (I already know about Kinsport Lighthouse and the crater house). I play on ps4, so no console commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [outfits listing on Nukapedia](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_armor_and_clothing#Outfits) lists *nine* different types of Child of Atom rags.

Most of them have the same locations as the "Long Rags" mentioned in [Vemonus's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/307107/108003).

> Possibly on a deceased Child of Atom at Jalbert Brothers Disposal.
>
> Found on a Child of Atom corpse on the lower level of the Sentinel site.

Additionally, the [Long Green Rags](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Child_of_Atom_long_green_rags) mention

> Possibly on a deceased Child of Atom at the Decayed reactor site.

Which probably applies to all nine types.

The [Long Brown Rags](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Child_of_Atom_long_brown_rags) also say

> On Child of Atom characters.

Which is of course true of all the rags. You can find randomly spawned groups of Children of Atom in various places around the Commonwealth.

The [Child of Atom article](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Child_of_Atom_(Fallout_4)) lists a few locations where you may find them randomly

> One may encounter Children of Atom fighting a group of three high-ranking Gunners as part of a random encounter, such as at the church in Hyde Park. They are often overwhelmed by the Gunners due to their combat armor often providing effective radiation resistance, and superior armor and weapons.
>
> One also may encounter four Children of Atom fighting a Gunner commander and Gunner conscript while defending a derelict building just north of College Square.

I personally remember encountering Children of Atom at a Drumline Diner near the [BATFL Regional Office](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/BADTFL_regional_office) a number of times.

In addition to some permanent locations

> Crater of Atom in the Glowing Sea, The Nucleus, and Brother Henri inside the Sentinel site

It's also a fairly common item of clothing for sale.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [wiki page](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Child_of_Atom_long_rags), there is no set location that they're guaranteed to spawn. However, you can potentially find them in the following spots:

> Possibly on a deceased Child of Atom at [Jalbert Brothers Disposal](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Jalbert_Brothers_Disposal).
>
> Found on a Child of Atom corpse on the lower level of the [Sentinel site](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Sentinel_site).